# Add checkbox to edit bool value of user in devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a `user` using `devise` `gem`. I have added a column `admin` to the `User` table which has `boolean` value. Now what I need is to add checkboxes after every `user` in `users_page` and give a feature so that when the checkbox is checked the value of `admin` column changes to `true`. How can I add the functionality?

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def users_page
    @users = User.all
  end

  def change_user_role    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    format.html { redirect_to users, notice: 'Role changed successfully' }
  end



  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
end
```

**users_page.html.erb**

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>

  <h5><%= user.email %></h5>

  <%= user.admin %>
  <%= form_tag({controller: "users", action: "change_user_role"}, method: "get") do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:admin, checked: false) %>
  <p><%= submit_tag 'Submit Answer' %></p>

  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", admin_destroy_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do   

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'users/users_page'

  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
  get 'users#change_user_role'

end
```

Here I should submit the value of the checkbox in `users_page` to `change_user_role` and update the value in db and redirect it to `users_page`. How can I do that?

Comment: There are many mistakes in you code. First of all, you are destroying the user twice in `destroy` method, second, your are using get method to update the database. third you are not binding the user attributes with your form controls to show the actual value of each user model.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. Could you please tell me how to rectify these errors?

Comment: which version of rails your are using?

Comment: Ruby on Rails version 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your `get` method to `put` in your **routes.rb** because you'll be updating the resource in database:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do   

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'users/users_page'

  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
  // it will require user id in your url
  resources :users do
    member do
      put :change_user_role
    end
  end
end
```

More on routes [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html)

**Then change your view to something like this:**

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>

  <h5><%= user.email %></h5>

  <%= form_for(user, url:  change_user_role_user_path(user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:admin) %>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Submit Answer' %></p>

  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", admin_destroy_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

More on forms [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

**Your controller should look something like this:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def users_page
    @users = User.all
  end

  def change_user_role    
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    // if user is updated successfully then redirect
    if(@user.update_attributes(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to users, notice: 'Role changed successfully' }
    end
  end



  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
  
  // new method added to allow specific attributes only and discarding other malicious attributes that user may send
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:admin)
  end
end
```

More on parameters [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Comment: I had to add `:method => :POST` in this line `<%= form_for(user, url:  change_user_role_user_path(user)) do |f| %>`. Thanks. This solved my problem.

Comment: I changed the `routes.rb` it should be `put` instead of `post` then you don't need to add `:method => POST`